# Determine complexity of a recursive function

Tags: c, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

I have to determine time complexity of the following recursive function with respect to K and n:

```
void fun(int K, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= K / pow(2, n - 1); i++) {
        fun(K / i, n - 1)
    }
}
```

I can provide time complexity analysis, but I doubt that it is correct.

In the worst case, function in for loop is called `(K / 2^(n-1) - 1)` times for each n.

In total, `(K / 2^(n-1) - 1)^n` times.

In **big O notation** complexity would be `O(K^n / 2^(n^2 - n))`. This is probably an upper bound but I doubt that this is a suitable solution.

**Any hints or suggestions appreciated.**

Comment: Have you tried to get the complexity and if you tried can you please help us out with that so that we can get an idea where you are stuck.

Comment: One thing you should do is move `K / pow(2, n - 1)` outside the loop. It's possible that the compiler may know about `pow` and do it for you (at a sufficiently high optimization level), but you can't count on that.  In fact, if `n` is an integer `>= 1`, you can replace the call to `pow` with `1 << (n - 1)`.

Comment: In fact, since you're just dividing by the exponential, you could replace `K / pow(2, n - 1)` with `K >> (n - 1)`, provided `K` is positive and `n >= 1`.  If `K` is negative, it may not round the way you want it to.

Comment: @AdityaShende I modified the question. I hope that helps.